# .NET 4.x Запрет ячеек на редактирование, DevExpress,GridControl, GridView

Tags: c#, devexpress, gridview

Требуется чтобы при загрузке формы все ячейки были заблокированы на редактирование. Далее в процессе работы когда мы выделяем какую-нибудь ячейку и нажимаем на кнопку, то выбранная ячейка становится доступной для редактирования.

Для обычного datagridview реализация такая :

1. На загрузку формы пишем цикл, который ставит блокировку :

   ```
   private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
               this.test_table12TableAdapter.Fill(this.bux_zatrDataSet.test_table12);


       for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount; i++)
       {

           dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].ReadOnly = true;
           dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].ReadOnly = true;
       }

   }
   ```
2. На кнопку пишем:

   ```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {

      dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ReadOnly = false; // CurrentCell возвращает текущую ячейку

   }
   ```

И все работает, но проблема в том что для работы необходимо использовать DevExpress и gridControl. Как реализовать данный способ с помощью DevExpress?

Answer (score 3):

Поскольку сам GridControl - всего лишь контейнер для представления (View), для запрета редактирования ячеек в представлении выставьте опцию OptionsBehavior.Editable в False при загрузке формы. В обработчике нажатия кнопки выставьте опцию обратно в True. Поглядите https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnViewOptionsBehavior_Editabletopic для большей информации.

В DevExpress гриде нет АПИ для доступа к конкретным ячейкам как в стандартном гриде. Если нужно запретить редактирование только конкретных ячеек, используйте https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_ShowingEditortopic ивент. В нем проверяйте FocusedRowHandle и FocusedColumn представления (gridView1.FocusedRowHandle и gridView.FocusedColumn) и в зависимости от данных выставляйте опцию e.Cancel в True для запрета редактирования.